# Residue thm on 1/(1+x^2) integrated over real axis, f(R)*2*pi*R says the integral over arc tends zero. Then f(R)*2*R says I over real axis also zero?

Tags: complex-analysis, residue-calculus

Residue theorem on evaluation of $\displaystyle\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \frac{1}{1+x^2} \mathrm{d}x$ makes uses of contour integral $\displaystyle\int_{\text{arc}+\text{real}} \frac{1}{1+z^2} \mathrm{d}z$ and argues that the portion over arc is bounded by $f(R)\cdot 2\pi R=\frac{2\pi R}{1+R^2}$ and therefore tends to zero as R tends to infinity. However, would not the same argument say that the portion over real is bounded by $f(R)\cdot 2 R=\frac{2 R}{1+R^2}$ and therefore also tends to zero as R tends to infinity ? Many thanks !

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The bound does not work for points on the real line. At $x=0$ the function has the value $1$ and the length of the line segment is $2R$ so you get the bound as $2R$ which tends to $\infty$ as $R \to \infty$.

Note that there are no points near  the origin the the semi-circle. That is the reason you are able to show that the integral over this arc tends to $0$.

Comment: Thank you for your very helpful answer !